# Intent ConfirmationStatus cannot be changed with Dialog.Delegate directive

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have a dialog where I delegate Alexa to collect two slots and ask the confirmation prompt. If the user says "no" to the confirmation prompt, I want to restart the dialog by deleting the slot values and setting the intent confirmationStatus to "NONE".

While Alexa starts to elicit the first slot, **the confirmation status remains as "DENIED"** which leads to a loop. I used the method described here to reset the status.

This is the updated intent sent back from my skill

```
{
  "name": "StartSingleGameIntent",
  "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
  "slots": {
    "player_one": {
      "name": "player_one",
      "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
      "source": "USER"
    },
    "player_two": {
      "name": "player_two",
      "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
      "source": "USER"
    }
  }
}
```

But the next request still has the "DENIED" status:

```
{
  "name": "StartSingleGameIntent",
  "confirmationStatus": "DENIED",
  "slots": {
    "player_one": {
      "name": "player_one",
      "value": "ben",
      "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
      "source": "USER"
    },
    "player_two": {
      "name": "player_two",
      "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
    }
  }
}
```

Here are my handlers:

```
const StartSingleGameStartedIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest' &&
      Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'StartGameIntent' &&
      Alexa.getDialogState(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'STARTED';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
             .addDelegateDirective(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent).getResponse();
  }
};
```

```
const StartSingleGameInProgressIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest' &&
      Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'StartGameIntent' &&
      Alexa.getDialogState(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IN_PROGRESS';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const currentIntent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;
    console.log("Dialog in progress %s", JSON.stringify(currentIntent));
    if (currentIntent.confirmationStatus === "DENIED") {
      let intent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;
      intent.confirmationStatus = "NONE";
      Object.keys(intent.slots).forEach(slotName => {
        const slot = intent.slots[slotName];
        delete slot.value;
      });
      console.log("New intent %s", JSON.stringify(intent));
      const speechText = "Ok, let's try again";
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechText)
        .addDirective({
          type: "Dialog.Delegate",
          updatedIntent: intent
        })
        .getResponse();

    }
    // if Intent is confirmed, delegate to complete dialog
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.addDelegateDirective(currentIntent).getResponse();
  }
};
```

```
const StartSingleGameCompletedIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest' &&
      Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'StartGameIntent' &&
      Alexa.getDialogState(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'COMPLETED';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log("Status COMPLETED");
    const currentIntent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;
    const playerOne = currentIntent.slots.player_one.value;
    const playerTwo = currentIntent.slots.player_two.value;
    const speech = 'Ok, ' + playerOne + ' versus ' + playerTwo + '!';
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speech).withShouldEndSession(true).getResponse();
  }
};
```

And here is the relevant part from the interaction model

```
{
  "interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
      "invocationName": "kicker tracker",
      "intents": [
        {
          "name": "StartSingleGameIntent",
          "slots": [
            {
              "name": "player_one",
              "type": "AMAZON.FirstName",
              "samples": [
                "{player_one}"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "player_two",
              "type": "AMAZON.FirstName",
              "samples": [
                "{player_two}"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "samples": [
            "{player_one} versus {player_two}",
            "{player_one} against {player_two}"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "types": []
    },
    "dialog": {
      "intents": [
        {
          "name": "StartGameIntent",
          "delegationStrategy": "SKILL_RESPONSE",
          "confirmationRequired": true,
          "prompts": {
            "confirmation": "Confirm.Intent.331442628749"
          },
          "slots": [
            {
              "name": "player_one",
              "type": "AMAZON.FirstName",
              "confirmationRequired": false,
              "elicitationRequired": true,
              "prompts": {
                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.1074854715089.1393950695631"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "player_two",
              "type": "AMAZON.FirstName",
              "confirmationRequired": false,
              "elicitationRequired": true,
              "prompts": {
                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.1074854715089.404108193608"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
    },
    "prompts": [
      {
        "id": "Elicit.Slot.1074854715089.1393950695631",
        "variations": [
          {
            "type": "PlainText",
            "value": "Who is the first player?"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "Elicit.Slot.1074854715089.404108193608",
        "variations": [
          {
            "type": "PlainText",
            "value": "Who plays against {player_one} ?"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "Confirm.Intent.331442628749",
        "variations": [
          {
            "type": "PlainText",
            "value": "{player_one} versus {player_two}, correct?"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```